# Querying multiple tables and displaying the outcome wtih SQL and Access

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access

I need to display the customers that have purchased a product (based on a user search) in a list box. I have five different tables in Access which store different information and that relate to each other with IDs (using combox boxes in vb). I need to be able to search for a product, for example "White Bread", the program then should display the customer's full name and address as stored in the database.

```
Table: TransactionDetails
Fields: ID, stockID, custTransID

Table: CustomerTransaction
Fields: ID, custID, dateOfTransaction

Table: CustomerAccountDetails
Fields: ID, custFullName, custAddress, custLandline, 
        custMobile, custDOB, custCreditDetails

Table: StockDescription
Fields: ID, stockName, stockDesc, stockPrice

Table: SupplierDetails
Fields: ID, supplierName, supplier Address
```

I think I need to use INNER JOIN to query multiple tables at once but I am unsure of the syntax (I'm new to SQL). So far I have this:

```
Dim productSearch As String

    productSearch = productSrchInput.Text

    Dim databaseConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim array(10) As String

    databaseConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=assignment5database.accdb"

    databaseConnection.Open()

    Dim searchDatabase As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT CustomerAccountDetails.custFullName, CustomerAccountDetails.custAddress " & _
                                                          "FROM CustomerAccountDetails " & _
                                                          "INNER JOIN StockDescription ON TransactionDetails.stockID = TransactionDetails.custTransID " & _
                                                          "WHERE StockDescription.stockName = '" & productSearch & "'", databaseConnection)
    Dim searchResults As OleDbDataReader = searchDatabase.ExecuteReader

    counter = 1

    Do While searchResults.Read
        srchResultsList.Items.Add(searchResults.Item(0))
        counter += 1
    Loop
    databaseConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Have you tried building the query in MS Access using the query design window? There are a number of wizards and joins are drag and drop.

Comment: The above Code JOINS `Customers` with `StockDescription`, where it should have another JOIN with the `TransactionDetail` table.

Comment: Joins in MS Access can get complicated - it is very fussy about brackets, hence my suggestion.

Comment: @Fionnuala - Absolutely. I think I pushed **Add Comment**, after which I saw your comment. However, the OP needs to add this table to the Query design to begin with. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some of the joins that connect the customer to the stock details. Here is the SQL that Access will expect in order to pull the data based on your description. The parentheses may seem extraneous, if you are used to SQL server or MySQL, but Access will throw a fit if you leave them out.

```
SELECT CustomerAccountDetails.custFullName, CustomerAccountDetails.custAddress, StockDescription.stockName
FROM StockDescription 
    INNER JOIN ((CustomerAccountDetails 
    INNER JOIN CustomerTransaction ON CustomerAccountDetails.ID = CustomerTransaction.custID) 
    INNER JOIN TransactionDetails ON CustomerTransaction.ID = TransactionDetails.custTransID) ON StockDescription.ID = TransactionDetails.StockID
WHERE StockDescription.stockName="something"
```

As noted by Fionnuala, I will almost always build a query that has multiple joins in it using the Access query designer before putting it in code. I almost always leave out a set of parentheses or try to write the query in a structure that SQL Server would expect and get rejected by Access.

Answer (score -2):

I think you could be able to use an inner join but perhaps a "union" may be more efficient.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp is good for improving sql knowledge, it helped me a lot.

Comment: I do not see how a Union query is in any way relevant.

Comment: I hate to disagree. JOIN is what needs to be done. UNION is no place near the OP's requirement.